# Using Hpricot to get children elements

Tags: ruby, hpricot

If I have the following element with children elements inside, how do I go about accessing those children elements using Hpricot?

`<p><b>Code</b> <i>base</i> is <a href="#">cool</a> stuff dude!</p>`

Comment: Which child element do you want to access? An XPath expression is what you could use, with Hpricot's `search` method. If you post the element, maybe I can give you a hand

Comment: @William: The problem is that this could be dynamic. I am trying to grad all child elements inside of an HTML string

Comment: you could try `inner_html` on the parent element, check the hpricot docs (https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot/wiki/Hpricot-Basics) which might be able to lend a hand as well.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz, this is the second elementary Hpricot question you've asked today without showing any code. Please provide some samples of what you've tried already.

Comment: Doesn't Hpricot have documentation?

Answer (score 1):

By "children", do you mean direct children, or all children recursively?

You can get direct children easily.

```
irb(main):038:0> (doc/"p").first.children
=> [{elem <b> "Code" </b>}, " ", {elem <i> "base" </i>}, " is ", {elem <a href="#"> "cool" </a>}, " stuff dude!"]
irb(main):039:0>
```

If you want any particular one, also easy:

```
irb(main):057:0> (doc/"p").first.find_element "b"
=> {elem <b> "Code" </b>}
irb(main):058:0> (doc/"p").first.find_element "a"
=> {elem <a href="#"> "cool" </a>}
irb(main):059:0>
```

More details would help us help you!